# CORS origin always undefined when fetching data

Tags: javascript, fetch

Using this **server** configuration

```
import Cors from 'cors';

const cors = Cors({
   methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'HEAD'],
   allowedHeaders: 'X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version, X-Api-Authorize, X-Authorize',
   credentials: true,
   origin: (origin, callback) => {
       console.log("*** TESTING", origin);

       return callback(null, true);  // debug, otherwise nothing works
   },
   optionsSuccessStatus: 200 // some legacy browsers (IE11, various SmartTVs) choke on 204
});

const applyCors = async (req, res) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   cors(req, res, (result) => {
      if (result instanceof Error) {
         reject(result);
      } else {
         resolve(result);
      }
   });
});

export const apiMiddleware = handler => async (req, res) => {
   await applyCors(req, res);

   // ... req is extended with utils    

   return handler(req, res);
};
```

And a **client** fetch request like

```
const response = await fetch(`/api/data`, {
   credentials: 'same-origin',  // also tried "include"
   headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'X-Api-Authorize': 'secret'
   },
   method: 'GET'
});
```

The server `console.log` *always* prints

> *** TESTING undefined

When inspecting the request, I see the `X-Api-Authorize` header, but not `Origin`. What's missing?

Comment: `'Content-Type': 'application/json',` makes no sense when coupled with `method: 'GET'`. GET requests don't have bodies, so the body can't be JSON.

Comment: Thank you, but I extracted the relevant content. The actual request uses an all-purpose options which does include these headers. This is irrelevant to the question, but thank you for the comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> fetch(`/api/data`
> ```

That's a relative URL, so you are making a same-origin request.

The `origin` header is only included in cross-origin requests.

(That's a simplification, as jub0bs points out, there are [other times](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#append-a-request-origin-header) it will be included, but your code doesn't meet any of those conditions).

Comment: So, a client could just "omit" to send the `Origin` header and it would pass as a same-origin request automatically??

Comment: The browser is responsible for enforcing the same origin policy. JavaScript on [Mallory's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice_and_Bob#Cast_of_characters) website can't make the browser omit it when making a cross origin request.

Comment: sure, but malicious scripts may not comply with this requirement. So... you're saying that CORS is based on good faith?

Comment: As I just said, it doesn't matter if a malicious script doesn't comply. The script runs in a browser and the browser enforces the same origin policy, not the script.

Comment: But the server may receive a request from a malicious script; how do I validate that the query is really from same origin if the value is undefined?

Comment: If there is no origin header then either (a) it is a same origin request from JavaScript running in a browser so its fine *or* (b) it isn't a request from a browser so won't include [Alice's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice_and_Bob#Cast_of_characters) credentials that are stored in her browser and is also fine.

Comment: (Possibly you think that the Same Origin Policy / CORS is a way to stop an unauthenticated, public facing web service from being an unauthenticated, public facing web service: It isn't.)

Comment: Well, I think that this same origin thing is completely useless because it can be ignored, or faked. Just check the credentials, then! Or perhaps there is something I really do not understand, because from where I stand, this is just adding bytes to the code that does not guarantee to actually be secure.

Comment: JavaScript running on Mallory's website **can't** make the browser ignore or fake the Origin header. So when Alice logs into Bob's website and then visits Mallory's website, Mallory's JavaScript can't make an HTTP request to Bob's website from Alice's browser and get Alice's data. The browser stops her because it enforces the Same Origin Policy.

Comment: The idea behind securing an API is to prevent malicious requests made by non-legit origins. Perhaps this does prevent typical cases but it does nothing against actual malicious code. This is just adding an extra layer that pretends to make things secure.

Comment: There are many different kinds of threat. The Same Origin Policy is very good at protecting against the kind of threats it is designed to protect against. CORS is very good at selectively turning the Same Origin Policy off when you want to permit cross origin requests. Just because it doesn't do what you want it to do (which still isn't clear) doesn't mean it is "pretending".

Comment: @YanickRochon CORS is to protect *code running in the browser*. Not really the server. You can bypass it trivially by *not* issuing a request from a browser. But if you go to a website that tries to steal the credentials from your bank account or even just authorise a payment via an API, it will be blocked. And you, as a user, most likely won't make a request via Postman (or whatever) to your bank trying to send an unknown person money and/or to a malicious domain to share your credentials.

Comment: @Quentin _The origin header is only included in cross-origin requests._ Sadly, it's not as simple as that. For instance, a same-origin `PUT` request will contain an `Origin` header. More generally, [this section of the Fetch standard](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#append-a-request-origin-header) stipulates in which condition browser should add the `Origin` header to a request.

Comment: As @Quentin wrote, the SOP is enforced by browsers. CORS is a mechanism that allow servers to instruct browsers to relax the SOP's restrictions for some _clients_ (i.e. JS code running in browsers in the context of a specific Web origin). The purpose of the SOP is not to protect the server, but to protect Web origins against other (potentially malicious) Web origins.

Comment: About your first comment, the answer is no. A cross-origin client cannot (at least not in a Fetch-compliant browser) suppress the `Origin` header. The most a client can do is get the value of that header to be `null`.

Comment: When a malicious client is positioned within the same Web origin (as is the case when your website is vulnerable to XSS), you've already lost all the benefits of the SOP.